# A preference relation $\succ$ is defined as $(x_1,y_1)\succ (x_2,y_2)$ if $x_1>x_2$ and $y_1> y_2$

Tags: microeconomics, preferences

Does this satisfy completeness property? I need an intuitive explanation of this preference relation as well.

I am confused about the way how this relation is defined. The commodity Y in the first bundle is strictly preferred to the commodity Y in second bundle.

Comment: What's the definition of the completeness property? Perhaps that could be a good start.

Comment: What happens if you compare $(1,6)$ against $(2,3)$, and $(1,6)$ against $(4,5)$, and $(2,3)$ against $(4,5)$?

Answer (score 0):

Completeness property says that for any $a,b\in R$ with $a=(x_1,y_1)$ and $b=(x_2,y_2)$ , $\:$ $a\succ b$ or $b\succ a$ or both must be satisfied. However for any $x_1\le x_2$ and $y_2\le y_1$ neither $a\succ b$ nor $b\succ a$ , thus the completeness property doesn't satisfied.